# How to multiply permutations together?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

This is straight from an exam question:
Find the order of the permutation $(1465732)(358)(79)$ in $S_9$

So I understand that I first have to write this permutation in disjoint cycle notation, but I'm having trouble doing so. For example if you look at 3, (going from right to left) we have

$ 3 \to 5 $, $ 5\to 7$ so in effect $3 \to 7$

But then we also have from the first cycle $3 \to 2$?

So where is 3 actually sent by this composition of permutations? Thanks.

Comment: Your first part was correct. The $3\to 2$ part will only have effect on some element sent to $3$ by the previous cycles.

Comment: I hope that you aren't still in that exam ;)

Comment: Nope, past paper question :D @cfh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just recall that the product of these cycles is just composition of maps. So if you apply your permutation $(1465732)(358)(79)$  to $3$ you will have
$$
(1465732) \circ (358) \circ (79) \ 3
=
(1465732) \circ (358) \ 3
=
(1465732) \ 5
=
7.
$$